# RSelenium Radio Button click doesn't seem to be working

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver

My example is:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
remDr$navigate("http://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/")
remDr$findElement("id", "three")$click()
```

Which doesn't seem to work. Can someone help with what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Looking at `?remoteDriver` the `click` method is described as:

`click(buttonId = 0)
Click any mouse button (at the coordinates set by the last mouseMoveToLocation() command). buttonId - any one of 'LEFT'/0 'MIDDLE'/1 'RIGHT'/2. Defaults to 'LEFT'`

This method is for clicking at a location on the screen. Your code can be changed slightly so that the `findElement` method result is assigned.

```
library(RSelenium)
# startServer() # start Selenium Server if needed
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
remDr$navigate("http://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/")
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "three")

> class(webElem)
[1] "webElement"
attr(,"package")
[1] "RSelenium"
```

Looking at the documentation for the `webElement` class there is a method `clickElement`:

```
webElem$clickElement()
```

Using this method should produce the required result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but the things that I found over various forums didn't work for me.

1. Using clickElement() method: which is explained by https://stackoverflow.com/a/26727185/5940139

```r
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "three")
webElem$clickElement()
```

2. Using sending enter key to element. https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/20#issuecomment-499974957

```r
webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "three")
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key="enter"))
```

3. Executing javascript code in browser.

```r
remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('three').click()")
```

The last one somehow worked for me when the first two didn't work for me.