# RSelenium: click button?

Tags: r, rselenium

I am trying to scrape a page, getting the move list of a game of chess, which is located in the menu on the right, under the "moves" tab.

[image: target]

```
library(RSelenium)
url <- "https://play.xiangqi.com/game/oX00ly"

rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser = "firefox", check = F)
remDr <- rD$client

remDr$navigate(url = url)
```

when manually clicking the Moves tab in the browser, I can get the desired text via

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css selector", ".Wrapper__MovesTabWrapper-sc-13rqht3-2")
webElem$getElementText()[[1]]
```

which (correctly) returns

```
[1] "1\np3+1\nP3+1\n2\ne3+5\nH2+3\n3\nh8+7\nH8+7\n4\nh2+3\nR1+1\n5\nc8=9\nH3+2\n6\nc2+1\nE7+5\n7\nh3+4\nA6+5\n8\nh4+3\nR9=6\n9\nr1=3\nR6+6\n10\nc2+2\nH2+3\n11\nr9=8\nC2=3\n12\nr8+3\nR1=4\n13\nc2-1\nR6=8\n14\nr8+4\nH3+1\n15\ne7+9\nC3+5\n16\ne9-7\nR4+3\n17\nc2=1\nR8=9\n18\nh3-4\nR4=6\n19\nc1=2\nR9-1\n20\nr3=2\nC8+7\n21\ne5-3\nR9=8\n22\nh4-3\nR8+2\n23\nh3-2\nR8+2\n24\ne7+5\nH7+8\n25\nr8-5\nC3+1\n26\nr8+2\nH8+7\n27\np9+1\nH7+5\n28\na6+5\nH5+7\n29\nk5=6\nR6=4\n30\na5+6\nR4+3"
```

## Problem

When trying to click the button through `RSelenium`, by using

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css selector", "#moves-tab")
webElem <-webElem$clickElement() # or webElem$click()
```

Nothing seems to happen, and I'm at a loss on how to proceed troubleshooting.

## Question

How can I switch to the Moves tab by simulating a click (active event listener)?

*Bonus pts: is this possible using the `rvest` package?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RSelenium Radio Button click doesn't seem to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26725406/rselenium-radio-button-click-doesnt-seem-to-be-working)

Comment: The problem in my case was the waiting for the execution, not the write-up for a click action. But for completeness, the post Earl mentioned suggests using `remDr$executeScript("document.getElementById('moves-tab').click()")`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33127514/selenium-tests-running-too-fast-not-waiting-for-the-radio-button-to-be-selected?rq=1, which I found after I found the solution, reports on the same issue, but using java tags.  As far as I can see, the `Sys.sleep()` is written in some `RSelenium` questions, but is not mentioned as source for silent erroneous outcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes being too trigger happy is a problem.

Adding

```
webElem <- webElem$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(2)
```

solved the problem.